# Interior and Closure of $Y = \{(x,0) | x \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset X = \Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Say $Y = \{(x,0) | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subset of $X = \Bbb R^2$ with the product topology coming from the standard topology on $\Bbb R$

I'm trying to find the interior and closure of this subset.

My immediate assumption assumption for the closure is:

We know that the closure is the smallest closed set containing $Y$ and $Y$ itself seems infinite for the infinite number of pairs $(x,0)$ that can be generated by $x \in \Bbb R$.

Hence we have an infinite set with a closure, in which case the closure of $Y$ must be $X = \Bbb R^2$.

I would assume that the interior is the empty set by thinking about $(0,0$ as a possible outcome for $Y$ as given.

Does this look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interior is empty, since no point in $Y$ is an interior point, your statement about this is right. However $Y$ is closed since any other point outside $Y$ will have a neighbourhood small enough such that it is disjoint to $Y$, for example, consider a circle small enough. Thus no point outside $Y$ is a limit point of $Y$, which illustrates that $Y$ is closed.